# Outputting XML with XSLT processing-instruction PHP

Tags: php, xml, xslt, processing-instruction

I have the following XML:

```
<content>
  <p>Para one</p>
  <p>Para two</p>
  <img src='pic.jpg' alt='pic'/>
</content>
```

In my XSLT I have

```
<xsl:processing-instruction name="php">
    $content = "<xsl:copy-of select="content/node()"/>";
</xsl:processing-instruction>
```

But it's outputting:

```
$content = "Para one
Para two";
```

I want it to output:

```
$content = "<p>Para one</p><p>Para two</p><img src='pic.jpg' alt=='pic'/>";
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Can you add a small, self-containing PHP example that demonstrates the issue? `xsl:copy-of` sounds fitting to me btw.

Comment: How would I add a self-contained PHP example?

Comment: create a small .php file that when executed shows your issue. It should contain a string containing the input XML, the XSLT XML and then echo the output. E.g. work in terminal or with sites like eval.in  - e.g. https://eval.in/private/9a14b67327ad30

Comment: @hakre I don't understand how that helps. The problem is with how the XSLT is outputting the content, not PHP. Or can you make PHP evaluate as if it were XSLT?

Comment: From your tags I did assume you are using PHP's DomDocument to do the XSLT processing (and yes you can register PHP functions then), having a self-contained example then would have allowed me to fiddle with it. As always in such a case, a self-contained example allows to easily reproduce the issue which most often is helpful in finding an answer. This is regardless of the programming language btw. It's just that I might have misread the meaning of the PHP-tag here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This script](http://www.getsymphony.com/download/xslt-utilities/view/79266/) as well as [this script](https://github.com/iwyg/xml-nodeset-to-string) gave me the result I desired:

```
<xsl:include href="nodetostring.xsl"/>
<xsl:template match="content">
    <xsl:param name="content">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="nodetostring" select="node()"/>
    </xsl:param>
    <xsl:processing-instruction name="php">
        $content = '<xsl:copy-of select="$content"/>';
    </xsl:processing-instruction>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, `copy-of="node()"` retrieves the child nodes of an element. But in the case of processing instructions it seems that only text content is output.

This does not make sense to me, but the solution below is a workaround for this.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/content">
   <xsl:processing-instruction name="php">
       <xsl:text>$content = "</xsl:text>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
       <xsl:text>";</xsl:text>
   </xsl:processing-instruction>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="content/*">
    <xsl:text>&lt;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/><xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>&lt;/</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/><xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?php $content = "<p>Para one</p><p>Para two</p>";?>
```

Comment: This does not explain why `xsl:copy-of` does not work here, nor does it work for tags different to `<p>`.

Comment: @hakre you're right - I am sorry for blaming you so hastily. I have adapted my stylesheet and I am about to explain why the `copy-of` does not work.

Comment: Just seeing the update. It's a bit of a pitty that the OP didn't post an example to reproduce, then I would have played a little with it.

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't copy attributes of the content. Sorry, I should have put that into the original question. It also doesn't allow for elements like `<img src="pic.jpg"/>`. How would I get those elements? I'll amend my question. Tx.